# Splitting table PK values into roughly same-size ranges

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in Postgres with about half a million rows and an integer primary key.

I'd like to split its entire PK space into N ranges of approximately same size for independent processing. How do I best do it?

I apparently can do it by fetching all PK values to a client and remember every N-th value. This does a full scan and a fetch of all the values, while I only want no more than N+1 of them.

I can select min and max values and cut the range, but if the PKs are not distributed quite evenly, it may give me some ranges of seriously different sizes.

I want ranges for index-based access later on, so any modulo-based tricks do mot apply.

Is there any nice SQL-based solution that does not involve fetching all the keys to a client? Writing an N-specific query, e.g. with N clauses, if fine.

An example:

IDs in a range, say, from 1234 to 567890, N = 4.

I'd like to get 4 numbers, say 127123, 254789, 379860, so than there are *approximately* 125k records in each of the ranges of IDs [1234, 127123], [127123, 254789], [254789, 379860], [379860, 567890].

*Update:*

I've come up with a solution like this:

```
select 
     percentile_disc(0.25) within group (order by c.id) over() as pct_25
    ,percentile_disc(0.50) within group (order by c.id) over() as pct_50
    ,percentile_disc(0.75) within group (order by c.id) over() as pct_75
from customer c
limit 1
;
```

It does a decent job of giving me the exact range boundaries, and runs only a few seconds, which is fine for my purposes.

What bothers me is that I have to add the `limit 1` clause to get just one row. Without it, I receive identical rows, one per record in the table. Is there a better way to get just a one row of the percentiles?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help explain what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `row_number()` for this purpose.  Something like this:

```
select t.*,
       floor((seqnum * N) / cnt) as range
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by pk) - 1 as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from t
     ) t;
```

This assumes by range that you mean ranges on pk values.  You can also move the range expression to a `where` clause to just select one particular range.